# Why does my solution of this Fatou's Lemma fail?

Tags: real-analysis

This is question question 1.8 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis.

> Put $f_n= \chi_E$ if n is odd, $f_n= 1-\chi_E$ if n is even. What is the relevance of this example to Fatou's lemma?

**My attempt:** Suppose $x \in E$. then  $f_n$ = 1 if n odd and =0 if n even. Thus $\liminf_nf_n$ =0. Thus, the left handed side of Fatou's lemma =0. Now focus on the RHS of Fatou's lemma. $\int_X f_n d\mu$ = $\mu (E)$ if n odd and =0 if n even. Thus, $\liminf \int_X f_n d\mu$ =0. Well, I prove that equality can occur in Fatou's lemma. (if $x \notin E$ is similar).

But the correct solution shows that strict inequality can occur in Fatou's lemma. So please point out my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: What is $E$? Do you mean $X$?

Comment: No, here E is a subset of X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\liminf_nf_n=0$; hence $\int \liminf_n f_n\mu=0$.
$$\int f_n\,d\mu=\left\{\begin{array}{lcr} \mu(E) & \text{if} & n\equiv1\mod 2\\
\mu(E^c) &\text{if} &n\equiv0\mod 2
\end{array}
\right.
$$
$$\liminf_n\int f_n\,d\mu=\min(\mu(E),\mu(E^c))$$

By choosing $E$ with $\mu(E)>0$ and $\mu(E^c)>0$, this exercise shows that strict inequality may occur in Fatou's Lemma.

Comment: I don't know how to get $\int f_n\,d\mu$

Comment: For any measurable set $A$, $\int \mathbb{1}_A\,d\mu=\mu(A)$. Also, notice that $1-\mathbb{1}_A=\mathbb{1}_{A^c}$. (I use $\mathbb{1}_A$ instead of $\chi_A$ since I am a probabilist and $\chi$ has a well establish meaning in probability)